# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xef' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, topic-modeling

I'm doing gibbs theme modeling，but it gives me an error.

I'm using the following code:

```
In[1]  import numpy as np
       import pandas as pd
       import gibbslda

In[2]  df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
       print(df.shape)
       list(df)
       
       ...Process of lematization

In[44] texts = [[text for text in doc.split()] for doc in Y_data]
       gibbs = gibbslda.CGibbsLDA()
       gibbs.SetInputDocs(texts)
       print("Calculations...")

In[45] texts[0] 

In[46] print("Calculations...")
       # Possible values of the parameter ldamethod:
       # "lda" - standart version of Gibbs sampling procedure
       # "granulate" - Vodel GLDA. in this case you must specify the granwnd parameter
       # "embeddings" - model with embeddings
       # out_dir="outcsv" - folder where the phi, theta matrices will be stored 

       gibbs.SetParameters(alpha=0.1, beta=0.1, topics=75, niters=200, nitersave=200,          ldamethod="lda", fixtopics = 0, granwnd = 0, out_dir="tang_outcsv")
       # If parameter ldamethod="embeddings", you need to call SetEmbeddings() and specify path to embeddings file and required number of words
       gibbs.StartCalculation()

       print("OK")
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Calculations...
Iterations done:  200
Python WNDPROC handler failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Topic_modeling\gibbslda.py in OnDataReady(self, hwnd, message, wparam, lparam)
     73             ArrayType = ctypes.c_void_p*self._doccnt
     74             dbl_ar = np.frombuffer(ArrayType.from_address(lparam), dtype=ctypes.c_void_p)
---> 75             self.saveTheta(dbl_ar, niter)
     76 
     77         if datatype==LDA_PHI:

C:\Topic_modeling\gibbslda.py in saveTheta(self, dbl_ar, niter)
    116                 # calc perplexity
    117                 if sng_ar[t]>doc_prob: sum_prob += 1
--> 118             writer.writerow(csvrow)
    119 
    120         ugof.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe1' in position 33: character maps to <undefined>

Python WNDPROC handler failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Topic_modeling\gibbslda.py in OnDataReady(self, hwnd, message, wparam, lparam)
     78             ArrayType = ctypes.c_void_p*self._topics
     79             dbl_ar = np.frombuffer(ArrayType.from_address(lparam), dtype=ctypes.c_void_p)
---> 80             self.savePhi(dbl_ar, niter)
     81 
     82         if datatype==LDA_NW:

C:\Topic_modeling\gibbslda.py in savePhi(self, dbl_ar, niter)
    143                 # calc perplexity
    144                 if sng_ar[wrdid]>cur_prob: sum_prob += 1
--> 145             writer.writerow(csvrow)
    146 
    147         ugof.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xef' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>

OK
```

After lematization data processing, clean texts data were obtained and then subject modeling was performed（in44,45）.

What can I do to fix this?

I tried similar posts on the forum, but still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please confirm this is with a python3 kernel. What is the value of `sys.stdout.encoding` ? Why does your `.read_csv` call mention `encoding='utf-8'` , and does behavior change if you omit it? (Yes, we definitely want utf-8 everywhere!) What can we do to alter the codec used by `.saveTheta()` or its `writer` ? Are you using https://pypi.org/project/lda ?

Comment: This is happening under python3 kernel. I omitted encoding='utf-8' ,, and the behavior remains the same.

Comment: poma you're going to have to do some Debug heavy lifting here, given that you're the only one who can observe the symptom. I cannot reproduce it, based on what you've disclosed so far. Where did that LDA code come from, and is it solidly tested? Which `charmap` codec is that, and where did it come from? Does your machine often use non-English languages, or non-unicode encodings like CP1252 ? Reduce the corpus / vocabulary you're working with so there is no symptom, then work your way back up so a single small change triggers it, and describe your findings.

Comment: I solved the problem by adjusting the code to cp1251.Thank you for your help！